iOS 18.2: Entitlements for Default Calling/Messaging App (Apple Developer Portal)
I’m trying to prepare my app to be the default calling and messaging app on iOS by following Apple’s documentation:

Preparing Your App to Be the Default Calling App
Preparing Your App to Be the Default Messaging App

I added the required entitlements (com.apple.developer.calling-app and com.apple.developer.messaging-app) and tried to build to a real device, but I keep getting the following errors:

"Provisioning profile <profile> doesn't include the com.apple.developer.calling-app and com.apple.developer.messaging-app entitlements."

When I checked Apple’s Developer portal, I found the new "Critical Messaging" capability, but not the capabilities for setting my app as the default calling and messaging app.
Has anyone managed to get the right entitlements for building and deploying to a real (not just simulator) device?
Any tips on getting Apple to add these entitlements to the provisioning profile?
Thanks!

I had been looking on an Enterprise Account, but these entitlements are only available on App Store accounts:

